# Is the size of a penis when erect proportional to its size when flaccid?

Tags: physiology

I've heard this most commonly in that you're either a shower or a grower.

For example [this site](http://forum.bodybuilding.com/showthread.php?t=125381891&page=1) talks about the claim accepting it as true.

Is there any proof that a smaller flaccid penis (<10cm) can result in a larger penis when erect, than a penis which is large when flaccid (>12.5cm)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**[Penile length in the flaccid and erect states](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8709382)** (1996):

> **METHOD**:
>
> We prospectively **measured flaccid and erect penile dimensions in 80
> physically normal men before and after pharmacological erection**.
>
> **RESULTS**:
>
> Mean flaccid length was 8.8 cm., stretched length 12.4 cm. and erect
> length 12.9 cm.
>
> **Neither patient age nor size of the flaccid penis
> accurately predicted erectile length**. Stretched length most closely
> correlated with erect length.

**More:**

- [Summaries of several studies regarding "Penile Size"](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=penis%20erect%20flaccid%20study%2080&source=web&cd=11&ved=0CCQQFjAAOAo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.medscape.com%2Fviewarticle%2F584195_2&ei=fmUuT43yOIGMswb42-GIDQ&usg=AFQjCNGhfq8nofnlhiU1c9ZMHJfMbPaKJw)

Comment: A direct link to Medscape doesn't seem to work (_asks for a Login_ ), that's why I'm using a Google redirect link.

Answer (score 10):

The Kinsey Institute's [Penis Size FAQ](http://www.kinseyinstitute.org/resources/bib-penis.html) explains:

> There is a much wider range of size in men's penises when flaccid, with the average ranging from 2.5cm to 10cm (1 to 4 inches). In general, smaller flaccid penises lengthen at erection by a greater percentage than do larger flaccid penises, with most men reaching an average size of 12.5cm to 17.5cm (5 to 7 inches), so the **flaccid size of a penis is not a good predictor of erect size**.

They do not link to a particular study, but provide general references, including to

- Jamison, P.L., and Gebhard, P.G. (1988). Penis size increase between flaccid and erect states: An analysis of the Kinsey data. Journal of Sex Research, 24, 177-183.